# Executing commands from Python script

Tags: python, build-automation

I am working on automation of flashing process of a development board.
I have an command line flashing tool which allows me to execute various commands required for flashing the board.

I am trying automate the same with a Python script.
I am using subProcess.Popen to start the .exe and then I need to execute other commands.
I have posted below the sudo code:

1. `process = subprocess.Popen(filename.exe, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
2. `process.communicate(arg)`
   I also tried with
3. `subProcess.stdin(arg)`

But I am not able to get desired result. 
I tried with creating batch file and then running it form Python but no luck there too. It just starts the exe and then closes it.

Can any one help me in solving this issue. I have just started with Python scripting so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.system() ( http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system ) to execute another program out of python.

Comment: `os.system` is older and less secure ( see your link) than `subprocess` the OP is using the correct module. [This link](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) shows you how to do so.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick answers. But my problem is I have a executable file, I am able to open it with Popen. It opens a console window, after I get console, I need to execute some commands on this particular console. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your question, you are trying to execute a series commands right?
For example:

```
filename.exe arg1 arg2
file2.exe arg3 arg4
```

The easiest way to do that is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['filename.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
subprocess.check_output(['file2.exe', 'arg3', 'arg4'])
```

docs for [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Answer (score 0):

What about simple append the argument to the command string like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('%s %s' % (filename, args), shell=True)
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "shell=True", as you probably don't need to run your exe program through the shell.
For the arguments, it goes that way:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['filename.exe', arg1, arg2], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```